# Simple API setup to retrieve YouTube search results via keyword

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm looking for a way to get back a list of YouTube videos with details such as: view count, rating, file name, length, etc. for a keyword or set of keywords. I have very basic coding knowledge, but appreciate any help on how to do something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) for searching YouTube videos.

Over here is a example [code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples), and you can also try it out yourself over [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it).